# inject a collection with particular number of prototype beans

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I want to inject in any type of collection or array a particular number of beans with prototype scope. Is there a way to do it declaratively?

```
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Bean
    public static State state() {
        return new State();
    }
```

and somewhere I declare

```
List<State> states;
```

and I want to inject in this List particular number of Beans

Comment: Can you show example for what you ask ?

Comment: I ve added an example